# Limit entries in SQL database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

Recently I developed a program in Java that stores some information in a MySQL database of mine. However, someone decompiled the code enough to get the SQL user information and flood the database with entries.

Is there a way I can limit the number of entries that come from a particular IP? If not, what alternative can I use to avoid this issue while still having information passed from my program into my database?

Comment: How did they get the code?  Are you sure you did not put SQL into your JSP?

Comment: Don't allow direct SQL access to your database if you're handing your program to end-users.  Instead, you should provide an API and sanitize your input.  Relevant: http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/1641/itsfinetrustme.png

Comment: Don't put the SQL user credentials in the code! Instead, have the program read them from a file, from the command-line args, etc.

Comment: well... if your page is allowing injection then that's just bollocks, rewrite your code, if you really just leaked the passwords you can just restrict the access for the user you use to connect to MySQL to the ip where you're running your application, that's easy enough

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a *service.*

Instead of accessing a database directly from the application, you have to make your application a client to RPC service, which will be an interface to the database.

But as long as you keep database credentials right in the application code, there is no point in devising whatever irrelevant measures like limited number of entries and such.

Comment: But if someone were to decompile the code again, couldn't they just re-write and execute the RPC call over and over to flood the database still?

Comment: Look. this site is just like this service. As well as any other site in the Net. There are always means to restrict users in their activity. Simple but effective. CAPTCHA is a last resort, yet there are other measures.